# Spinner.setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-spinner

This is my code :

```
transactionTypeSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something changed", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But unfortunately `OnItemClickListener` method not working and show this message : `setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.`

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not call `OnItemClickListener` for a spinner. A Spinner does not support item click events.

```
 transactionTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something changed", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } // to close the onItemSelected
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
        {

        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**`setOnItemSelectedListener()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener))

> Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been selected.

Use

```
transactionTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()
```

instead of

```
transactionTypeSpinner.setOnItemClickListener()
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    transactionTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something changed", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following code hope will help you

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if(selectedItem.equals("Add new category"))
            {
                 // do your stuff
            }
        } // to close the onItemSelected
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
        {

        }           
    });
```